# Return array () in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML list

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="50" class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Item do Pacote</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Vencimento</th>
            <th width="50" class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">1</td>
            <td>Salgados - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 150,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="itens[0][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[0][item]" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="150,00|1"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">2</td>
            <td>Doces - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 114,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="itens[1][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[1][item]" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="114,00|2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">3</td>
            <td>Refrigerante - 10 un</td>
            <td>R$ 85,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control array_teste" name="itens[2][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[2][item]" id="itens[item]" class="array_teste" value="85,00|3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to retrieve all this data that is inside the fields, through a jQuery.
I tried to do it this way:

```
$("#salvar_festa").click(function() {

    var itens = $(".array_teste").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: basePath + 'evento/salvar_festa',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            itens: itens
        },
    })
    .done(function(ret) {
        console.log("success");
        $('#mensagePage').html(ret);
    }); 

});
```

But in this way, I can not return the array objects, which should return as follows:

```
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-05
                [itens] => 150,00|1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-07
                [itens] => 114,00|2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-22
                [itens] => 85,00|3
            )               
    )
```

But I have no idea how to resolve this issue.
Within the save_fest in PHP, I then have print_r ($_POST);

My return via print_r ($_POST):

```
Array
(
    [itens] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[0][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[0][item]
                    [value] => 150,00|1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[1][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[1][item]
                    [value] => 114,00|2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[2][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[2][item]
                    [value] => 85,00|3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What? Please reword your question. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I need to retrieve this data through a jQuery, and pass via PHP to a $_POST.

Comment: OK. And what problem are you running into?

Comment: I have edited the question, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `.serialize()` http://jqapi.com/#p=serialize

not `.serializeArray()` http://jqapi.com/#p=serializeArray

the difference is: if you use .serializeArray() you need to iterate through them to get the correct value and this function is usually for debugging only (unless you really need it for some reason)